# Error while creating Multimedia component for youtube videos. Invalid value for property 'Filename'

Tags: sdl-tridion, sites-9

I am trying to create a multimedia component for youtube videos.I have created the following schema allowing Mpeg Video type.

[image]

However, if I try to create a multimedia component with external URL, it is throwing an exception reated to file extension.

```
Invalid value for property 'Filename'. Unexpected file extension: . Expecting: mpg,MPEG.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you need to add allowed extensions for this file type.
So go to **Administration**, then **Multimedia types** and select type there and update it.

[image]

Comment: Well, looking at the error message, the unexpected file extension is an empty string. You would have to add an empty string as File Extension on the MM type; I don't think that is allowed.  So: the root cause here seems to be that there is no file extension in the URL.

Comment: true. not sure about youtube video in link....

Comment: Hi @MarkoMilic, Thanks for the response. Could you tell me what extension type should be updated for youtube video url?

Answer (score 2):

Why not implement as already proven in this implementation?

You don't have to use DXA to render the final piece - any application can consume the same content but at least you'll be using something that's tried, tested and even documented.

https://docs.rws.com/792161/548870/sdl-digital-experience-accelerator-2-1/adding-a-youtube-video-to-a-webpage